# Recommender System based on item-item features evaluation method

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

The idea is to recommend books purely on the characteristics of it without any user's input (ratings) only getting top N books that are the most similar to a book.

I am implementing Euclidean distance to find the most similar vector among a dataframe.

So I was wondering if there is a way to test or evaluate what I am doing ? like for example in machine learning models we use recall, precision etc.. but in this case what should I use?

or for example if I use cosine similarity , how can I tell which is better?

Thanks in advance.